# How do I make jQuery animation only display within div container/banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a image that fades in and animates from bottom simultaneously inside of a container/banner.

container style:

```
#nix_banner {
margin: auto;
background: #1f1f1f;
width: 1200px; 
height: 300px;
}
```

script:

```
 $('#wavy')
    .hide()
    .fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 3000})
    .animate({'bottom': '355px'}, 3000);
```

Consider an ad at the top of a webpage. When an animation occurs in the ad the user sees nothing leave the ad banner. Both animations work but I do not want the image showing anywhere outside of the banner. What am I supposed to do to keep only what is inside the container visible?

I am also open to any complete alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;`:

```
#nix_banner {
    margin: auto;
    background: #1f1f1f;
    width: 1200px; 
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/g77cxn25/)

Comment: Thanks @turbopipp, That sent me in the right direction to get it working. I also had to make the position relative.